# MySQL : can we automatically increase a field every time the row is selected for appearing in query results?

Tags: mysql

I would like to perform statistics on a table row, especially counting for each row the number of times it has been selecting for appearing in query results.

Of course, the first solution is to add a column named 'counter' with a default value of 0 and to increase this value for each row that appear for each query. Unfortunately, this solution increase the number of DB queries.

Maybe, a similar native mechanism exists in MySQL like for timestamps, i.e. the timestamps can be automatically updated every time the row is updated :

```
ALTER TABLE `Test` 
CHANGE `timestamp` `timestamp` 
TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Here is an example. Assume the following table:

```
id  title        counter
1   Hello        0
2   Good morning 0
3   Good bye     5
```

After the following query for example `select * from Test where id > 1;`, I would like the counter column to be updated automatically like this:

```
id  title        counter
1   Hello        0
2   Good morning 1
3   Good bye     6
```

So, my question is: **can we automatically increase a field every time the row is selected for appearing in query results?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Speaking for myself, I'm not 100% clear on the goal here. Can you add an example expectation to the question?

Comment: @PaulT. I edited the question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding You can try using stored procedures but in this method you will all ways have to use the stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER ;;
create procedure count_increase(in id int)
begin
select * from test;
update test set counter= counter+1
where id = id;
end ;;
DELIMITER ;;
```

Comment: Yes, your understanding is perfect. What I understand from your answer is that I'll have to call manually the stored procedure on each row from each query?

Comment: Yea that's how we can do this